# Check if input is positive integer

Tags: python

I need to check whether what the user entered is positive. If it is not I need to print an error in the form of a msgbox.

```
number = input("Enter a number: ")
   ###################################

   try:
      val = int(number)
   except ValueError:
      print("That's not an int!")
```

The above code doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Check that the integer is greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: You mean `if val  >= 0`

Comment: after getting `val`, check it if it's greater than 0. if so, throw another exception.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Office\Desktop\Python\If Else\Program\program.py", line 4, in <module>
    number = input("Enter a number: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined

Answer (score 24):

```
while True:
    number = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        val = int(number)
        if val < 0:  # if not a positive int print message and ask for input again
            print("Sorry, input must be a positive integer, try again")
            continue
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not an int!")     
# else all is good, val is >=  0 and an integer
print(val)
```

Comment: Nope............. still same error.

Comment: there is no error in my code and what error are you talking about?

Comment: My full code: http://pastebin.com/yctSQLz0

Comment: I have answered your question as posted, if you have another problem you should ask another question and fyi your code you posted in pastebin works fine

Comment: @shivampaw that isn't even remotely related to the code that Padraic posted (or the traceback you posted, for that matter).

Comment: Noting that this code only works with Python 3.x. Python 2.x users should use raw_input() instead of input(), since the latter does not even catch user errors, and parses user input before returning it.
I believe the very root of @shivampaw 's problem was the mistaken use of the input() function instead of the correct raw_input(), which would have worked fine with his original traceback.

Comment: Can we just do `if number :` to check if its positive

Answer (score 2):

what you need is something like this:

```
goodinput = False
while not goodinput:
    try:
        number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        if number > 0:
            goodinput = True
            print("that's a good number. Well done!")
        else:
            print("that's not a positive number. Try again: ")
    except ValueError:
        print("that's not an integer. Try again: ")
```

a while loop so code continues repeating until valid answer is given, and tests for the right input inside it.