# Most compact/Pythonic way to check if variable is a positive integer, possible variable types being any variable type including boolean

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out the most compact and pythonic way of checking if a variable is a positive integer. This is what I've tried so far.

```
a = None
b = 3.4
c = -1
d = 10
e = -5.7
f = '7'
g = [9]
h = {7}
i = 3j
j = r'8'
k = True
l = False

varlist = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j , k, l]

for vv in varlist:
    print( isinstance(vv, int) )
```

Current Output

```
False
False
True
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
True
```

Ideal Output

```
False
False
False
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: `isinstance() and > 0`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if input is positive integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198131/check-if-input-is-positive-integer)

Comment: Typo in question or ideal output? You have `c` as True and `d` as False, currently?

Comment: The answers in that post can convert a float to an int. What I am looking for is to tell me that float is an invalid input

Comment: @DavidBuck yes, fixed

Comment: @Sayse the solution works for all cases except for case `k = True'

Comment: `isinstance(vv, int) and not isinstance(vv, bool) and vv >= 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want exclusively `int` objects and no subtypes:

```
type(vv) is int and vv > 0:
    do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for vv in varlist:
    print( type(vv) == type(0) and vv > 0 )
```

Comment: `type(vv) == type(0)` right idea, but use `is` to compare types, which are language guaranteed singletons, and `int` is a built-in